# How can I tell if I’m part of a workgroup? Or just a stand-alone computer

Tags: networking, workgroup

How can I tell if (My laptop, running windows 10)if it part of a workgroup? Or just a stand-alone computer.

It’s totally doing my head in. I keep getting incorrect information.

Thanks in advance if anyone can tell me either way. It looks like it’s connected to a workgroup and I’m not the administrator even know I’m the only person who uses it and should be accessing it. Weird messages saying files are in use but I don’t have them open and some MBI ssl shared shit gonna on. Lol

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) Please ask us about the precise issue you are having, rather than what you think you might need to do to solve it.

Comment: All the info is in *Control Panel > System*. What is the real problem?

Answer (score 2):

Windows networking works as follows:

Either your computer is part of a workgroup or it is domain joined. There is no other choice, but a stand-alone computer can still be in a workgroup of just one computer.

For a domain joined pc, you must also have a server with domain, so if that is not something that is in your building, then this is already for sure a workgroup computer.

But luckily, we can just check and find out.

In windows 10, right-click the start menu button to get the little menu (don't actually open start menu), and select system to directly go to your system settings.

Find the section Related settings (either at the top right, or all the way at the bottom), and choose System info.

Below the section for `Settings for computername, domain and workgroup` you'll either find Domain:  or Workgroup: .

If it says domain, your computer is domain joined. If it says Workgroup, your computer is part of a workgroup instead.

Being in a workgroup is the default setting until you go into a domain, so its very likely that your computer is part of a work group.

That said, it seems like this is a classical X-Y problem. Something weird is going on, you are searching for a solution, think you found the cause of the solution and now troubleshoot that solution, but you ran into a problem and your question is about the 2nd problem, not the actual underlying problem. You may want to just ask help about solving the first problem, because I don't think being in a workgroup is at all the problem here, given that being in a workgroup is kinda the default setting.

Comment: Being "part of a workgroup" does very, very little -- it's essentially just for being able to list/discover computers in the LAN (and that mostly in NetBIOS/SMBv1 era), and the computers are completely standalone otherwise. But I wonder if OP might be confusing it with a Windows 7 "homegroup", which _does_ have an explicit membership with join/leave and has a shared account kind of thing.

Comment: @user1686 if that were the case, they'd not mention they're using Windows 10.